# How to use only one matching row of association table to join parents

Tags: sql, sql-server

Question title isn't the best. I have two parent tables A and B and their association table AB. I need columns from A and B, none from AB. For a given row in A, the multiple matching rows in B will always have identical values for the columns I want. Currently, I join the 3 tables and do a DISTINCT on B, but it is incredibly time-consuming. Here's example data:

```
Table A
    PK_A col1
    1  a
    2  b
    3  b

TAble B    
    PK_B col1
    5  R
    6  S
    7  T
    8  R
    9  R

Table AB    
    FK_A  FK_B
    1    5
    1    8
    1    9

    select
       A.col1,
       B.col1
    from A
    join AB
      on AB.FK_A = A.PK_A
     and AB,FK_B = B.PK_B
    join B
      on B.PK_B = AB.FK_B
```

returns

```
a   R
a   R
a   R
```

I add DISTINCT to get what I want.

Is there a speedier way to do this by forcing a join using only a single matching row in AB? Sort of like where FK_B = MAX(FK_B)?

It will always be the case that the B.col1 values I want for a given value of A.col1 are identical, the unique parameters in the association table aren't of interest in this query.

Comment: You SQL statement is wrong.  You have `B.col1` in the select list, but don't define what B is.

Comment: If you don't need any columns from that other table, do select from a where EXISTS (select ... from other table where a.col = b.col)

Comment: @jarlh - you comment makes no sense, he is doing a double join so EXISTS won't work.

Comment: @Hogan, maybe not, got a bit confused by different table names etc.

Comment: Yes the SQL was missing the other parent table B--just added. Thank you

Comment: I think you need to remove the part after the and -- maybe you should test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would do what you ask, I'm not sure if it would be faster than distinct but it will use just 1 row from the AB table.

```
select
   A.col1,
   B.col1
from A
join (select 
        FK_A,
        FK_B, 
        row_number() OVER (partition by FK_A ORDER BY FK_B) as rn
      from AB 
     ) jtable ON A.PK_A = jtalbe.FK_A AND rn = 1
join B ON B.PK_B = jtable.FK_B
```

How this works:

I use the `row_number() OVER` to "pull out" each row we want to join on from the joining table in a sub-query.

This may be faster than distinct but probably is dependent on what indexes you have defined relative size of tables etc.

Comment: Your solution runs in about a minute, returning the 1M row result set. I tried replacing your partition solution with one based on max()--same basic subquery but using max() on a 3rd column of AB to get just one row for each row in A. Doesn't seem to work (there's the key), returns 4 times as many records, and takes about 10 times as long to run.

Comment: [deleted a syntax question]

Comment: I can show you how when I get home but probably all you need to do is add a different order by in the over statement.  If you want max of A then order by A desc

Comment: No I wasn't clear--I don't want max() of anything, I was only saying that I *thought* an equivalent approach would be to use max() as the means by which you could ensure getting only one matching record out of AB. I'd probably have to do an example both to explain, AND for me to see why it didn't work when I tried it. Your solution works and works well.

Comment: @KirkFleming - I see.  The problem is max() only gets the field not the row.  You need the row association to stay because it is a linking table.  With row_number() you uniquely identify each row according to criteria and then you can get the whole row and maintain the relationship of items within the row by filtering on a value returned by row_number()